# How do you assign a value to different values in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

In this program I am putting values in an array those and the assign to those values a float number.
It should work like this:
Ex.

```
Formula name: Addition
how many unknown values?: 3
unknown value:x
unknown value:y
unknown value:z
enter the value of x: 2
enter the value of y: 3
enter the value of z:
```

(instead of writing `enter the value of y`, in the second-last line, it writes `enter the value of x` again)
how can I fix it?
This is the code:

```
import math
name = input('Formula name: ')
unknown_values = int(input('how may unknown values?: '))
unknown_array = []
for i in range(unknown_values):
    unknown_name = input('unknown value:')
    unknown_array += [unknown_name]

values = []
x = -1
for i in range(len(unknown_array)):
    values[i] += [input('enter the value of ' + str(unknown_array[x+1] + ': '))]

print(values)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain properly and try to comment your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't incrementing your `x` value inside of the second `for` loop, so it will always refer to the same element in `unknown_array`. In other words, in each iteration of the loop it will refer to `unknown_array[0]`, or the first unknown you input, which in your example is `x`. You should add a line to increment this value in the loop.

A couple of other things:

- `values[i] += ...` will produce an `IndexError` as these elements have not been initialized yet, I think you meant to write `values += ...` instead (or you can use `.append` rather than `+=`):
- Doing `str(unknown_array...` is unnecessary because `unknown_array` already stores `str`s, due to the return type of `input`

```
x = -1
for i in range(len(unknown_array)):
    values += [input('enter the value of ' + unknown_array[x+1] + ': ')]
    x += 1
```

Better yet, since `x + 1` is the same value as `i`, you should just use the `i` iterator instead of `x + 1`:

```
for i in range(len(unknown_array)):
    values += [input('enter the value of ' + unknown_array[i] + ': ')]
```